# preg_replace to add own website before every hyperlink

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

For a project, I need to fetch a websites content and alter the HTML code. Every link on that website has to be replaced with my own aswell. I used `str_replace` until I realized that links sometimes have classes assigned to them.

I've tried the `preg_replace` function to add my own website before every href link that is also between `<a>` `</a>` tags. It shouldn't matter whether or not the fetched website in `$content` contains `href=""` or `href=''`.

```
$content = preg_replace('~(<a\b[^>]*\shref=")([^"]*)(")~igs', '\1http://website.com/fetch.php?url=\2\3', $content);
```

This does not work and I can't find the error. It should behave as follows:

```
<a class="link" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

should turn into

```
<a class="link" href="http://website.com/fetch.php?url=http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Can someone help me find the error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use a regex, you will run into similar issues you found with `str_replace`. Use a parser. Also if not using a function you don't need `preg_replace_callback`, `preg_replace` will replace.... Also there is no `g` modifier in PHP. The functions are global.

Comment: It's preferable to use `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the replacement string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: When you use `preg_replace_callback`, the second argument must be a function, not a string. Did you mean to use `preg_replace`?

Comment: PHP doesn't allow the `g` modifier, because `preg_replace` always replaces all matches.

Comment: When I remove the `g` modifier your code works. Didn't you notice the error message from that?

Comment: Your code won't work if the href attribute uses single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Barmar even with your answers, it just seems to replace every `href` that comes right after the `<a>` tag. This is however a big step forward because previously it would replace nothing at all.

Comment: `$content = preg_replace('~(<a\b[^>]*\shref=")([^"]*)(")~is', '\1http://website.com/fetch.php?url=\2\3', $content);`

Comment: What do you mean? I tried it with the string above and it produced the desired result.

Comment: But as the linked question suggests, it's better to use a DOM parser instead of regexp to process HTML.

Comment: You should use `urlecode()` to encode the original URL when you put it into the parameter section. This will require going back to `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't half-arse a regex that will miss *plenty* of cases. Just read each document into a DOM tree (give this [html5 DOM parser](https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php) a go), and use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get all links with `href` attributes, and update them, then save the result.

Answer (score 0):

just use `simplexml` and `preg_replace`

```
        <?php

            $string= '<a class="link" href="http://google.com">Google</a>';

            $a = new SimpleXMLElement('<a class="link" href="http://google.com">Google</a>');

            $newurl="http://website.com/fetch.php?url=".urlencode($a['href']);

            $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";

            $body = preg_replace($pattern,$newurl,$string);

            echo $body;


         ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<a class="link" href="http://website.com/fetch.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com">Google</a>
```